# Cannot use Tor browser when specifying control port

Tags: proxy, tor

I downloaded the latest version of Tor.

In `Data/Tor/torrc` I added the following:

```
ControlPort 9051
HashedControlPassword <generated from tor>
```

But once I have this, the tor browser does not start up. I get a message that says "Could not connect to control port" (or something to that effect).

When I remove the `ControlPort` line, the browser starts up fine. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? i have the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i figured it out.  With TBB you don't need to set port.  It is already set to 9151.  Just set the HashedControlPassword in your torrc file like you did with the value you get from:

tor --hash-password yourPassword

Then you can telnet and authenticate like:
telnet localhost 9151
then:
AUTHENTICATE yourPassword

...